# c# : get nr of google hits for a search term

Tags: c#, search

I'm writing a C# forms app, and I have list of strings (descriptions of some thing or another).
I'd like to sort that list based on the amount of hits Google returns for each string.

So how do I actually get the amount of google-hits for a specified search-term ?
Do I need to go screen-scraping, or is there an easy solution ?

Cheers :)

Edit:
To clarify and show my simplest case of use :
Suppose I have a text input box, and a button "Get amount of hits"...
When the button is pressed, I want a label to show the amount of hits Google returns for the specified text.
So - in a desktop application, how do I get the amount of Google-hits for a specific string ?

Answer (score 1):

Ugly way that comes to mind :

Launch request to `http://www.google.com/search?q=your+request`
Extract number from `<div id=resultStats>`.

Yuk.

Comment: It's also against the Google Search terms of use `)-:`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/dev_guide.html) for this

Comment: Thanks!
But reading this it looks overly complicated for just getting the amount of hits for a certain search-term in a desktop application - it seems aimed at people wanting to create a custom search application for the web ?

Comment: I have no practical experience with it, just know it exists :-)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's complicated, just limiting. You need an API key and then can only call the API 100 times per day for free.